# How to append to a file-backed mmap using the memmap crate?

Tags: linux, rust, mmap

I have a file `foo.txt` with the content

```
foobar
```

I want to continuously append to this file and have access to the modified file.

#### `MmapMut`

The first thing I tried is to mutate the mmap directly:

```
use memmap;
use std::fs;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let backing_file = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .append(true)
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .open("foo.txt")?;

    let mut mmap = unsafe { memmap::MmapMut::map_mut(&backing_file)? };

    loop {
        println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&mmap[..])?);
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5));
        let buf = b"somestring";
        (&mut mmap[..]).write_all(buf)?;
        mmap.flush()?;
    }
}
```

This will result in a panic:

```
Error: Custom { kind: WriteZero, error: StringError("failed to write whole buffer") }
```

The resulting file reads `somest`

#### Appending to the backing file directly

After that, I tried to append to the backing file directly:

```
use memmap;
use std::fs;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let mut backing_file = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .append(true)
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .open("foo.txt")?;

    let mmap = unsafe { memmap::MmapMut::map_mut(&backing_file)? };

    loop {
        println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&mmap[..])?);
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5));
        let buf = b"somestring";
        backing_file.write_all(buf)?;
        backing_file.flush()?;
    }
}
```

This does not result in a panic. The file will get updated regularly, but my mmap does not reflect these changes. I expected standard output to look like this:

```
foobar
foobarsomestring
foobarsomestringsomestring
...
```

But I got

```
foobar
foobar
foobar
...
```

I am mainly interested in a Linux solution if it is platform-dependent.

Comment: That crate is already suspicious as *every single access* of an mmapped file is unsafe by Rust's terms. That type allows you to access the file while another process may be modifying it without any kind of guards.

Comment: See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4gnf34/is_appending_to_a_file_that_is_mmaped_safe_and/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460507/appending-to-a-memory-mapped-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, based on my understanding, I would urge you to be **highly suspicious of that crate**. It allows you do do things in safe Rust that you should *not*.

For example, if you have a file-backed mmap, then any process on your computer with the right permissions to the file can modify it. This means that:

1. It's never valid for the mmapped file to be treated as an immutable slice of bytes (`&[u8]`) because it might be mutated!
2. It's never valid for the mmapped file to be treated as a mutable slice of bytes (`&mut [u8]`) because a mutable reference implies an exclusive owner that can change that data, but you don't have that.

The [documentation for that crate](https://docs.rs/memmap/0.7.0/memmap/index.html) covers *none* of these concerns and doesn't discuss how you are supposed to use the small handful of `unsafe` functions in a safe manner. To me, these are signs that you may be introducing undefined behavior into your code, which is a Very Bad Thing.

For example:

```
use memmap;
use std::{fs, io::prelude::*};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let mut backing_file = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .append(true)
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .open("foo.txt")?;

    backing_file.write_all(b"initial")?;

    let mut mmap_mut = unsafe { memmap::MmapMut::map_mut(&backing_file)? };
    let mmap_immut = unsafe { memmap::Mmap::map(&backing_file)? };

    // Code after here violates the rules of references, but doesn't use `unsafe`
    let a_str: &str = std::str::from_utf8(&mmap_immut)?;
    println!("{}", a_str); // initial

    mmap_mut[0] = b'x';

    // Look, we just changed an "immutable reference"!
    println!("{}", a_str); // xnitial

    Ok(())
}
```

---

Since people generally don't like being told "no, don't do that, it's a bad idea", here's how to get your code to "work": directly append to the file and then recreate the mmap:

```
use memmap;
use std::{fs, io::prelude::*, thread, time::Duration};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let mut backing_file = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .append(true)
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .open("foo.txt")?;

    // mmap requires that the initial mapping be non-zero
    backing_file.write_all(b"initial")?;

    for _ in 0..3 {
        let mmap = unsafe { memmap::MmapMut::map_mut(&backing_file)? };

        // I think this line can introduce memory unsafety
        println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&mmap[..])?);

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));

        backing_file.write_all(b"somestring")?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

You may want to preallocate a "big" chunk of space in this file so that you can just open it up and start writing, instead of having to re-map it.

I would not use this code for anything where it's important that the data is correct, myself.

See also:

- [Is appending to a file that is Mmap-ed safe and cross-platform?](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4gnf34/is_appending_to_a_file_that_is_mmaped_safe_and/)
- [appending to a memory-mapped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460507/appending-to-a-memory-mapped-file)
- [How to create and write to memory mapped files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28516996/155423)